# Promises/Observables versus redirection

Tags: angular, http, keycloak

Hello Stack community,
I'm about to integrate some authentication server that will delegate login activity in angular application. The basic flow would look like following code:

```
authService.login()
.then((res) => {
  /* Check login operation result, parse token */
})
```

But consider that inside login function some redirection (to external login server) will took place:

```
login() {
  window.location.replace('URL-to-auth-server')
}
```

My question is, if redirection took place, then `then` function after `login` call will never be called, as redirection will reload page content, javascritps will be run once again even moving back to main page?

To be more specific, the integration is about KeyCloak and Angular 5. Only available network resources about pairing those two are using all-or-nothing approach: keycloak redirection is kicked in before Angular bootstrap procedure. If it fails, application will not load. I'd like to display certain parts of application without login, but restrict some API calls only for authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use one of the libraries available. I had good success of integrating KeyCloak and Angular with [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc)
Use Implicit Flow while redirecting to KeyCloaks Login page and receive the Access Token after login. You could use Angular's CanActivate Guard to do this based on URLS with restricted access. That means authentication/authorization kicks in only after the user navigates to a restricted path and no Access Token is in local-storage present.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made some further research on this and the results are following:

To answer my main question:
Promises/Observables flows are lost when redirection comes in, which is obvious. What misleads me was integration solution proposed by KeyCloak, where indirect promise use took place (i.e. promises were used only if user is already logged in):

1. Before bootstrapping web application authentication library is
   initialized
2. Library at initialization will check, does the authentication cookie
   exist

   - If yes, it will not redirect, but via standard XHR verify this
     cookie and continue bootstraping web application -> promise will work normally
   - If no, redirection will took place to external authentication server login 
     page -> promises will not be fulfilled for this application run
3. After external login is succeeded, authentication server will
   redirect once again to web application (authentication cookie is stored) and will starto once over again